# Comparing the Center of Mass of a Semicircular Ring and Semicircular Arc

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A Semicircular Ring can be considered to be made up of many Semicircular Arcs. A Semicircular Arc has its center of mass at ( 0, 2R/pi).

Turns out, a Semicircular Ring also has its center of mass at ( 0, 2R/pi).

Is there any intuitive explanation as to why both of their Center of Mass have the same coordinates?

Semicircular Ring:
[image]

Semicircular Arc:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Aren't both the shapes one and the same !?

Comment: You can include the pictures in the body of the question. This way it'll be easier to read and still work if the links break.

Comment: -1. Not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture of a ring you link to has "$t\ll r$", so it's being approximated by an arc.

Therefore your "ring" and your "arc" are the same thing, that's why they have the same center of mass.

An example of the center of mass calculation for the annulus can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1157909/418568).

Comment: I guess that must be the case, my book mentioned the thickness of the ring to be dr, which is the same as t≪r.  Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @Skb Just in case "ring" means "annulus", I've added a link to an example.